# How to limit Autobahn python subscriptions on a per session basis

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I am using autobahnpython with twisted (wamp) on server side and autobahnjs in browser. Is there a straight-forward way to allow/restrict subscriptions on a per session basis? For example, a client should not be able to subscribe to topics relavant to other users.

While I am NOT using crossbar.io, I tried using the Python code shown in the 'Example' section at the end of this page http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/ where a RPC call is first used to give authorization to a client. Of course, I am using my own authorization logic. Once this authorization is successful, I'd like to give the client privileges to subscribe to topics related only to this client, like 'com.example.user_id'. My issue is that even if auth passes, however, I have not found a way to limit subscription requests in the ApplicationSession class which is where the authorization takes place. How can I prevent a client who authorizes with user_id=user_a from subscribing to 'com.example.user_b'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can authorize by creating your own router.  To do that, subclass Router() and override (at a minumum) the authorize() method:

```
def authorize(self, session, uri, action):
    return True
```

This method is pretty simple, if you return a True then the session is authorized to do whatever it is attempting.  You could make a rule that all subscriptions must start with 'com.example.USER_ID', so, your python code would split the uri, take the third field, and compare it to the current session id, returning True if they match, false otherwise.  This is where things get a little weird though.  I have code that does a similar thing, here is my authorize() method:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def authorize(self, session, uri, action):
    authid = session._authid
    if authid is None:
        authid = 1
    log.msg("AuthorizeRouter.authorize: {} {} {} {} {}".format(authid,
        session._session_id, uri, IRouter.ACTION_TO_STRING[action], action))
    if authid != 1:
        rv = yield self.check_permission(authid, uri, IRouter.ACTION_TO_STRING[action])
    else:
        rv = yield True

    log.msg("AuthorizeRouter.authorize: rv is {}".format(rv))

    if not uri.startswith(self.svar['topic_base']):
        self.sessiondb.activity(session._session_id, uri, IRouter.ACTION_TO_STRING[action], rv)

    returnValue(rv)

    return
```

Note that I dive into the session to get the _authid, which is bad karma (I think) because I should not be looking at these private variables.  I don't know where else to get it, though.

Also, of note, this goes hand in hand with Authentication.  In my implementation, the _authid is the authenticated user id, which is similar to a unix user id (positive unique integer). I am pretty sure this can be anything, like a string, so you should be ok with your 'user_b' as the _auth_id if you wish.

-g

Comment: For what it's worth, `@inlineCallbacks def foo(): return bar` is effectively a syntax error.  Any function decorated with `@inlineCallbacks` *must* have a `yield` expression somewhere in its body.

Comment: FWIW, the approach outlined in the answer (creating a custom router) is no longer supported by AutobahnPython (since 0.9.4). Creating custom routers should not be required for app developers. The way forward (when using Crossbar.io as a WAMP router) is indeed described here http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/ - "dynamic/custom authorization".

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively simple solution using a Node guest. Here's the code:

```
    // crossbar setup
var autobahn = require('autobahn');

var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
        url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws',
        realm: 'realm1'
    }
);

// Websocket to Scratch setup
// pull in the required node packages and assign variables for the entities
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var ipPort = 1234; // ip port number for Scratch to use

// this connection is a crossbar connection
connection.onopen = function (session) {

    // create an http server that will be used to contain a WebSocket server
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        // We are not processing any HTTP, so this is an empty function. 'server' is a wrapper for the
        // WebSocketServer we are going to create below.
    });

    // Create an IP listener using the http server
    server.listen(ipPort, function () {
        console.log('Webserver created and listening on port ' + ipPort);
    });

    // create the WebSocket Server and associate it with the httpServer
    var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        httpServer: server
    });

    // WebSocket server has been activated and a 'request' message has been received from client websocket
    wsServer.on('request', function (request) {
        // accept a connection request from Xi4S
        //myconnection is the WS connection to Scratch
        myconnection = request.accept(null, request.origin); // The server is now 'online'

        // Process Xi4S messages
        myconnection.on('message', function (message) {

            console.log('message received: ' + message.utf8Data);
            session.publish('com.serial.data', [message.utf8Data]);

            // Process each message type received
            myconnection.on('close', function (myconnection) {
                console.log('Client closed connection');
                boardReset();
            });
        });
    });
};

connection.open();
```